# SQL java get value assigned to auto increment primary key

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a primary key auto increment attribute in my table. I want to know the value assigned to it for a row that is inserted using statement.executeUpdate(). How to achieve this in the best possible manner?

Comment: For what database?  You could use the RETURNING clause for Oracle/DB2 (and possibly Postgres); LAST_INSERT_ID for MySQL; @SCOPE_IDENTITY for SQL Server...

Comment: @OMGPonies: JDBC abstracts the way databases implement this (when supported by the database).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Statement#getGeneratedKeys()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) and [`Statement#executeUpdate(String, int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (this is a JDBC 3.0 feature, your database has to support JDBC 3.0).

Here's an example that returns a `ResultSet` with values for auto-generated columns in TABLE1:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLE1 (C11, C12) VALUES (1,1)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

Comment: i get an error saying column id not found when i call rs.getInt("id");
what could be the reason?

Comment: something related.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18409
but even this does not solve the problem

Comment: my column has a datatype of int(11). i am using mysql

Comment: @iamrohitbanga Did you try to retrieve the column by index `rs.getInt(1);`?

Comment: yes i did. i still get an exception. 
i have posted a new question here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854774/sql-jdbc-getgeneratedkeys-returns-column-id-not-found-column-type-unknown

Comment: i have put up the stack trace as well as the datatypes of the columns in the table. see the link above.

Comment: does not work work oracle