# Method to create object which uses callback

Tags: java, mysql, asynchronous, callback, bukkit

I'm implementing simple Jail system for Minecraft server.
Jails are objects, they have their own id, amount of players inside and location.

I want to create simple method to create new Jail.

```
public static Jail createJail(final Location location);
```

This method should automatically insert newly created Jail into DB using my DBhelper (which runs everything async) and if something fails, return null instead of Jail object. The problem is of course with callBack and anonymous class implementing my simple CallBack interface, because I'm unable to return anything within inner anonymous class.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Create new Jail object, fill with values and register in List
 * @param id Unique id of Jail, usually got from DB
 * @param location Location of Jail
 */
private Jail(final int id, final Location location) {
    this.id = id;
    this.location = location;
    this.amountOfJailed = 0;
    jails.add(id, this);
}
```

```
/**
 * Tries to create new Jail<br />
 * New Jail will be auto-inserted into DB.
 * @param location Valid Bukkit Location
 * @return Jail if successfully created, null otherwise
 */
public static Jail createJail(final Location location) {
    if (location == null) {
        Bukkit.getLogger().warning(Lang.PREFIX + " Tried to create new Jail with invalid location");
        return null;
    }

    final Jail newJail;

    DatabaseQuery db = new DatabaseQuery();
    db.insertJail(location, new SimpleCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryDone(ResultSet result) {
            if (result == null) {
                newJail = null;
            } else {
                result.next();
                int usedId = result.getInt("id");
                newJail = new Jail(usedId, location);
            }
        }
    });

    return newJail;
}
```

and DatabaseQuery#insertJail

```
/**
 * Inserts Jail into DB<br />
 * When any error happens, callBack will receive null ResultSet<br />
 * When everything goes well, ResultSet will hold generated id
 * @param location Location of inserted Jail
 * @param callBack Class with 'onQueryDone' method to be executed
 */
public void insertJail(final Location location, final SimpleCallBack callBack) {
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ResultSet result = null;
            try
            {
                Connection connection = hikari.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO p_jails (`location`) VALUES (?);");
                statement.setString(1, Serializer.location_serialize(location));
                statement.executeUpdate();
                result = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final ResultSet fResult = result;
            new BukkitRunnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callBack.onQueryDone(fResult);
                }
            }.runTask(Main.coreapi);
        }
    }.runTaskAsynchronously(Main.coreapi);
}
```

How am I supposed to implement method `createJail`? I need to know whether it was inserted into DB successfully and I need to get used id from ResultSet so I can eventually return that Jail object and tell him something like "Successfully created new Jail with ID ##".

Comment: Its just very simple interface with `void onQueryDone(ResultSet result);` method

Comment: Because that first `BukkitRunnable` makes it Async. Then I callback to sync thread sometimes called tick thread by Bukkit. When I split it to two methods, it won't help, because I need to return `Jail` object from within `createJail` method... but only if properly saved into DB. That split would just make from one query two queries. First to get free ID and then to save `Jail` into DB.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `CompletableFuture` in your code. Your method should have a signature like:

```
public static CompletableFuture<Jail> createJail(final Location location)
```

This method return immediately a `CompletableFuture` for a Jail object which it will be available later.

You can create easily a `CompletableFuture` instance, and you can easily set a value (success) or an exception (failure) on it. For exemple, set the inserted jail instance after database performed  the operation. For this, see the doc for methods [complete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete-T-) and [completeExceptionnaly()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-)

Then, add a (or several) callback on the completable future to do something in case of success or failure :

```
future.thenAccept( jail -> { /* do something */ } );
future.exceptionnaly( exception -> { /* do something */ } );
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer for [sql jdbc getgeneratedkeys returns column "id" not found, column type unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854774/sql-jdbc-getgeneratedkeys-returns-column-id-not-found-column-type-unknown)

I have borrowed the code from the top answer in this thread.

After `result = statement.getGeneratedKeys();` you nee to get the generated ID from the result set. The code will look like

```
int autoIncKeyFromApi = -1;
rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
    autoIncKeyFromApi = rs.getInt(1); // "autoIncKeyFromApi" is th generated key
    // Write the code to construct a Jail object here 
    Jail newJail = new Jail(); 
    newJail.setID(autoIncKeyFromApi);
    // Set all other fields 
} else {
   // Did not have a generated key either because no rows were inserted or yur query does not have a generated key column
}
System.out.println(autoIncKeyFromApi);
```

If you created the SimpleCallBack class yourself, Change the signature of the `callBack.onQueryDone(fResult);` to pass an object of "Jail" or a common superclass of all the entities in your system. The call back will look like 'callBack.onQueryDone(newJail);' . Note that callbacks primarily work with parameters and not return types.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. The problem in this question is not receiving auto-increment ID from DB but returning created object with that ID from within wrapping method.

Comment: If I pass the Jail object itself into callBack, how can I return it from within `createJail` method? It should be returned only if DB query was successfully completed.